# $item->getProduct()->getQty not working in magento

Tags: magento

I wrote a function in `shipping.php`. I want to get the quantity from each product in the cart. I am using `$item->getProduct()->getQty`, but this is not working.
Is there any other method?

Comment: Post the complete relevant code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried `$item->getQty()` ?

Answer (score 6):

For future readers: look into the relevant source code, e.g `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/` to find the exact API.

In that case, the code you are looking for is probably `$item->getQtyOrdered()`. Not sure which one you're referring to above.

Comment: $item->getQty() worked up until version .. um, 1..5; but it was simply a convenience function and the better practice has always been to use $item->getQtyOrdered() for items in a quote, $item->getQtyShipped() for items that have been shipped, and so on ...

Comment: If you arrived here and realise this is a Magento 1.9 solution, and you are unlucky enough to be on Magento 2, try `app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Item.php`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
            $result = array();
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
                $result[$i]['id'] = $item->getProduct()->getId();
                $result[$i]['name'] = $item->getName();
                $result[$i]['sku'] = $item->getSku();
                $result[$i]['price'] = $item->getPrice();
                $result[$i]['qty'] = $item->getQty();
                $i++;
            }
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($result);
```

Try this.

You can use

```
$item->getId();
```

to get the cart product ID too.

`$item->getProduct()->getQty`; will be returned by NULL;